# A map $f:X \to X$ takes $A \subseteq X$ to $A \subseteq X$ induces a quotient map - where fails when doesn't take $A \subseteq X$ to $A \subseteq X$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm a bit new to quotient maps and I'm struggling to understand the following:

If a map $f:X \to X$ takes $A \subseteq X$ to $A \subseteq X$, I can see why it immediately induce a quotient map:

$$ f': X \to X/A$$
$$ x \mapsto [f(x)]$$

but I don't see where it might fail if the condition "$f:X \to X$ takes $A \subseteq X$ to $A \subseteq X$" is not satisfied. I tried thinking of the following example:

$ X = [0,1]$ and $A = \{0,1\}$ (which means $X/A = S^1$)

and $$f: X \to X$$
$$0 \mapsto 0.5$$
$$x\neq 0 \mapsto x$$

but can't see what might be wrong with that (it's onto; not sure about the open sets condition, but if I'm not mistaken, it does hold - so maybe this is not a good counter example).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is it well-defined? $[f(0)]=[0.5]$ but $[f(a)]=[0]$ for all $a\in A.$

Comment: You don't need any hypothesis for *that* definition of "inducing a quotient map": your $f'$ is just the composition $q_A\circ f$, where $q_A$ is the quotient map, and it's continuous as soon as $f$ is. You need some hypothesis if you want a map $\tilde f:X/A\to X/A$ such that $\tilde f\circ q_A=q_A\circ f$. However, $f[A]\subseteq A$ is not necessary, but you do need $\left.f\right\rvert_A$ constant or $f[A]\subseteq A$ (i.e. that $q_A\circ f$ is constant on $A$).